# Reordering rows in a database queue that are out of order

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I have a database table that is tracking list of items, they get inserted in and removed when necessary. I found a bunch of rows that are lout of order and i wanted to have something take care of it upon insertion or removal of a row.

Currently, I'm using basic insert statements

```
insert into this_queue (thing, queNum) VALUES ('thing1', 1)

delete from this_queue where thing = 'thing1'

update this_queue set queNum = queNum - 1 where queNum > 1
```

These queries work fine for deleteing a single item from the queue but when i delete items that are not in order it throws everything out of whack.

I have been trying to figure out the best way to have the queue numbers in order, ie... 1, 2, 3,4, 5,6, etc... when an item gets added or removed.

I was thinking about after the insert or delete to either remove or add 1 check if the adjacent number is there, if not count again, keep track and keep going until i find the number. Then i could subtract the number and get back to square one.

I included python in the tag list as i am using python and mssql server 2008r2.

This seems a little messy to me so i was hoping someone would have a more elegant way. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
CREATE TABLE Test_Order(Thing varchar(50), queNum INT) 
GO

INSERT INTO Test_Order (Thing, queNum) VALUES
('thing 1', 1),('thing 2', 2),('thing 3', 3),
('thing 4', 4),('thing 5', 5),('thing 6', 6),
('thing 7', 7),('thing 8', 8),('thing 9', 9)
GO
```

**Table**

```
╔═════════╦════════╗
║  Thing  ║ queNum ║
╠═════════╬════════╣
║ thing 1 ║      1 ║
║ thing 2 ║      2 ║
║ thing 3 ║      3 ║
║ thing 4 ║      4 ║
║ thing 5 ║      5 ║
║ thing 6 ║      6 ║
║ thing 7 ║      7 ║
║ thing 8 ║      8 ║
║ thing 9 ║      9 ║
╚═════════╩════════╝
```

**Delete Some random Records**

```
DELETE FROM Test_Order WHERE queNum IN (2, 4, 6)
```

**Update Table**

Update the table using ROW_NUMBER() function with CTE.

```
;With CTE
AS
 (
  SELECT  Thing
         ,queNum
         ,rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY queNum)
  FROM Test_Order
 )
UPDATE CTE
SET queNum = rn
```

**OR**

Update the table using INNER JOIN with ROW_NUMBER() Function

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.queNum = T2.rn
FROM Test_Order T1 INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT  Thing
         ,queNum
         ,rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY queNum)
  FROM Test_Order
)T2
ON T1.Thing = T2.Thing 
AND T1.queNum = T2.queNum
```

**Final Result**

```
SELECT * FROM Test_Order

╔═════════╦════════╗
║  Thing  ║ queNum ║
╠═════════╬════════╣
║ thing 1 ║      1 ║
║ thing 3 ║      2 ║
║ thing 5 ║      3 ║
║ thing 7 ║      4 ║
║ thing 8 ║      5 ║
║ thing 9 ║      6 ║
╚═════════╩════════╝
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of that feature, or the with statement. let me give it a shot

Comment: WITH function is actually syntax for CTE `Comman Table Expression` , and row_number() is a ranking function in sql server. very useful for some very tricky operations in sql server.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CTE, i need to research it

Comment: Just one more question, why the ; before the with statement on the CTE? Thanks